# Fix elements jumping around when fading with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, fadein, fadeout

Whenever I fade an element in our out using jQuery, the other elements, being centered vertically, kind of just jump around.

Here's a stripped down example of what I mean:

```js
$("#one").click(function(){
  $("#two").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">Paragraph 2</p>
```

When clicking on the first paragraph, the second fades out/in.

What I want to achieve is that instead of well, jumping around, I want it to animate (slide/scroll) between those two positions. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of .fadeToggle(), use .slideDown() and .slideUp ()

Answer (score 1):

To avoid jumping, you can use `slideToggle()`:

```js
$("#one").click(function() {
  $("#two").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Now that was simple. I wanted the second paragraph to fade in though (not slide in), but I guess this is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, set the position of first paragraph to relative:

```
#one {
   position: relative;
}
```

Then add the animation for the first paragraph:

```
$('#one').animate({top: animationType + topPos + 'px'});
```

The snippet:

```js
$("#one").on('click', function() {
    var topPos = Math.ceil($('#one').height());
    var animationType = '+=';
    if ($('#two').is(':not(:visible)')) {
      animationType = '-=';
      topPos = topPos;
    }

    $("#two").fadeToggle();
    $('#one').animate({top: animationType + topPos + 'px'}, 800);
});
```

```css
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#one {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<p id="one">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">Paragraph 2</p>
```